# Encrypt In .NET / Decrypt in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, encryption

Is there a way to decrypt a column when querying data from a SQL Server (2005/2008) database that has been encrypted using DES via .NET? If so, how? I have the key, but don't know how to use it within the context of a sql server query.

Comment: Was the encryption done in C# code and then written to SQL, or was it done using `EncryptByKey`?  You might consider moving to use the built-in SQL encryption /decryption if the former.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably consider [creating a CLR function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28VS.80%29.aspx) in SQL Server to handle this decryption.

You can use this function just like any other UDF within SQL Server to decrypt on demand.

That way, its as simple as using regular .NET C# code to handle it exactly the way you would do it in your application itself.

Comment: Yep, that's how I'd do it.  Though, you should carefully consider the use case - is it absolutely necessary to to the decryption in the database, rather than in some service layer?  Generally, the fewer times you have to pass the key around, the smaller the vulnerability footprint.

Comment: No it's health care related info, one way hashing won't do. I was leaning towards putting a service layer over it anyway, so in that case I don't even need to worry about SQL Server.